# sshpass в bash скрипте - вывод всех папок на сервере

Tags: bash, ssh

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой, использую `sshpass` пришла необходимость написать скрипт, но в скрипте данная команда не выводится

Если данную команду ввести в терминал, то у меня все работает и я получаю вывод всех скрытых папок у себя на сервере, но в самом скрипте она не работает

```
sshpass -p 'my_pswd' ssh srv@srv-server ls -a
```

Данный скрипт выводит пустое поле, как бы мне получить вывод - `ls -a`

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(sshpass -p 'my_pswd' ssh srv@srv-server ls -a)
echo $value
```

Также я пробовал

```
value=sshpass -p 'my_pswd' ssh srv@srv-server ls -a
echo $value
```

Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Нормальное решение — использовать ключи вместо паролей... если всё же хочешь оставить всё как есть, то на первый взгляд должно работать и в таком виде... для отладки могу посоветовать вывести *stdout*/*stderr* в файл — увидишь на что жалуются `sshpass`/`ssh`...

Comment: `echo "$newpass" | sshpass ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ls -a /`